# Is it alright to use logical punctuation?

Tags: grammar, dialogue, british-english

Since I have been writing, I have been using what I thought was just the British style of punctuation. However, I realised that it is actually called 'logical punctuation'.
I have used this style of punctuating since I first started to write and I cannot imagine myself not using it.

As in:

"Hello", he said. "How are you?" (Logical - the way I write)

Or

"Hello," he said. "How are you?" (The other way - I am not sure what the technical term for it is).

A few British English speakers have actually said my style of punctuating is wrong and the idea of having to change my style and rewrite my entire book terrifies the life out of me.

I have read a few articles and Quora answers and it seems it might be okay, but I need to double-check.

I also tried looking at literary works from British authors and a lot of them seem to the second style. Why is that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One is "punctuation", the other is "punctaution".

Comment: There is no such beast.[Could someone here please explain to me how posters make so many spelling mistakes. Don't they show up on their screens??]

Comment: There's nothing logical about throwing that comma outside of the quotation marks there. What's more, neither British grammar nor American grammar permit that. There's no such thing as "logical grammar." Now, what British grammar would allow, it notably calling for single quotes instead of double quotes, would be for me to instead have written in my last sentence that there was no such thing as 'logical grammar'. But for direct speech (i.e., dialogue), the rules for punctuation are the same, that being punctuation at the end of direct speech is to be placed within the quotation marks.

Comment: I’ve corrected the OP’s typo. It’s an interesting question, though I thought UK & US usage took opposite positions on the ‘inside/outside’ debate.

Comment: I'm Australian and use the British style in most cases. It's not logical to put punctuation that is not part of the quotation inside the quotation marks the way the American system does. But in your specific example perhaps that comma *is* part of the quotation.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Those who ban logic categorically from grammar show an obvious lack of concern for progress, as logic is a dependable system that enables us to think clearly and rapidly. There is no reason to decide that grammar is not logical because it happens that certain illogical practices have been introduced and nurtured. There is an enormous lot in grammar that is pure logic. Grammar is life and life is cold logic; if human grammar diverges somewhat it is due only to the  fact that it is shaped by beings with inherent  shortcomings.

Comment: In the British system you would write "Hello," he said. Because what he *actually* says is "Hello, how are you?" with a comma or "Hello. How are you?" with a period, and ***not*** "Hello How are you" with no punctuation. (And in the British system, freely converting between commas and periods is permitted.)

Comment: @PeterShor This argument is not valid: it is founded on a particular case. Here is another one that has nothing to do with this case of repeating a single occurrence (she was certainly not called "Mrs Piper," ) https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Journal_of_the_American_Society_for/9R9-AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22called+her+mrs%22&dq=%22called+her+mrs%22&printsec=frontcover  ':…he called her "Mrs. Piper," and it was by that appellation that she was known throughout her career.'

Comment: @LPH: It's not an argument. I am trying to explain how the British system of punctuation works.  In the British system, you would say *he called her "Mrs. Piper".* – with the period outside the quotes. Your link is to an American journal. Maybe you should look at a few books or newspapers actually published in the U.K.

Comment: @PeterShor I am aware of that, although it has been claimed that the "British system" is not uniform and tends to follow the American one. What I am saying is that the American system is not logical. Such inclusions as an exclamation point ("Hello!") do make sense as they can be said to make precise how the word was used, but a comma  is hardly justified, it is rather picky to make precise there was a slight pause after the word.

Comment: @PeterShor It seems to me that the ending punctuation in such reported utterances can't belong to the block (except, as I said, for an exclamation point, an interrogation point or suspension points, as those seem to be indications that are substantial enough about how the words are said, and as they concern the words themselves).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127698/discussion-on-question-by-user422154-is-it-alright-to-use-logical-punctuation).

Comment: More [info here](https://writingexplained.org/alright-vs-all-right-difference) related to your question.

Answer (score -3):

As I consider the question, it is not one of style, that is no question about using an artistic device that one is more or less free to choose among several possibilities so as to decorate the words or whatever, but one of  material necessity, and in fact prescribed by logic. However in the English speaking world this misnomer is solidly entrenched in the domain of linguistics and I will use it for convenience.

When you introduce quotes around a block of characters that way you do it in order to *suppress* in the sentence *the primary function* that these words have, which is that of  introducing referents and coding relations between them and with the referents represented by the other words (not in the block).

- This word is long. (*The string of characters is long. The referent of "word" (the particular one talked about,* this word) *is a word with many characters.*)
- This word is "long". (*The referent of "word" is "long"; the idea of length in "long" is no longer valid; this is strictly a logical suppression of the normal semantic function of the word in current language.*)

In this fundamental way of using quotes, as the quoted block is introduced in a sentence, it must impinge on it as a *constituent*, in other words, it must make sense. For instance the following is not readily decipherable.

- They talked "the car" because they have time.

The use of quotes involves many principles that are not well known. One important idea is that the practice of using quotes allows to talk about the written word as itself a referent; therefore for transitive verbs that make sense as applied to entities with strings of word (or characters) as referents the quoted blocks are quite natural in object territory.

- He said "Hello". He wrote "Hello". He spelled "Hello". He added "Hello" at the end of all his sentences.

Another likely territory, for instance, is in copulas (subject complement).

- These words look like "a root".  This combination of characters looks like a root.

It must be learned at the start that over the ages the human grammarians have introduced numerous exception, or have never considered necessary to apply the principle strictly, and this makes the use of quotes even more difficult.

- […] they call it "the garland"
- He called her Mrs Garland.
- […] he called her "Mrs Piper" ([ref](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Journal_of_the_American_Society_for/9R9-AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22called+her+mrs%22&dq=%22called+her+mrs%22&printsec=frontcover))

This brushing up of the basic use of quotes aims at describing their semantic function which is to remove the referents (the semantic function of representing these referents in the sentence) while still keeping to the block a grammatical function. The idea to retain for the present purpose is that the block must be inserted in the sentence as a meaningful constituent.
The commas that you use in your sentence are used to delimit and define constituents, essentially. Suppose that considering the constituent "during the summer" in the sentence

- "They go there during the summer, but never would dare do so in the winter.",

and then decide to place the comma after "the", or even after e in "summer";

- "They go there during the, summer but never would dare do so in the winter."
- "They go there during the summe,r but never would dare do so in the winter."

We obtain pure nonsense. This is why the comma has to be placed after the quote: it is not part of the block, its coding of a pause or whatever in the whole sentence is not removed: it has to be made *in the sentence* in order to read the sentence properly.

Therefore, the material necessity you perceive is real and there is no escaping it; to do so would be to deny elementary logic, to do yourself and the language a disservice.